# Does Apple allow us to send Credit Card information of the user from the app to the server for payment purpose?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway

> Does Apple allow us to send  Credit Card information of the user from the app to the server for payment purpose? Even though we are not going to save any card information on the server , will they accept to send Credit Card information to the web service which in turn will process the payment transactions.

Comment: You can only use alternative payment type for physical goods. Any digital goods need to use Apple In App Purchase,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes Apple Will Allow it.** I have Uploaded 3 Apps Which uses payment on server side and I'm accepting card info and sending to server via POST Method Also Server Should have Secure Socket Layer (e.g.HTTPS). If you are not saving the card then there is no worry at all. But If you are **saving card info on Local Storage then its not allowed**. Also If the Goods which you are sold not to be sold by In-App Purchase. If it can sold Via In-App then Apple Disapprove your app.

Answer (score 1):

In the US at least there are strict rules, dictated by the government, covering collection, transfer, and storage of financial information like credit cards. No, you most certainly cannot send credit card information in free-text over the internet.

For a small company you are probably better off licensing somebody else's payment system than trying to do this yourself, as complying with the rules is complex and there are liabilities involved.

Here is a link I found on PCI compliance:

http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/#11